# Postgres database inheritance, indexes on child tables

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, indexing

I'm having parent table product and child tables product_1 ... product_N based on field store ID. Once a day UPDATE operation is performed explicitly (and in different time) for all stores. So now I want to add index on some field and I'm not sure which table should have this index. Parent table only or every child table should have its own index? Or both?

**UPD**

```
UPDATE product p SET
 ...
FROM newitems n
WHERE n.new_prod='0' AND
      n.internal_product_id is not null AND
      p.sku = n.sku AND
      p.distributor_id=M and
      p.store_id=N;
```

I want to add index on sku field to make join faster.

Comment: It depends on, what do you want to query. In this state, your question is too broad, please extend it.

Comment: An index on the parent table doesn't help, it's empty. Create indexes on the tables that you use and the columns that are used in WHERE and JOIN conditions. Check your queries and the results from EXPLAIN ANALZE. An index (for all child tables) on the column sku makes sense.

Answer (score 9):

Index should be added explicitly on each table. Indexing parent table doesn't affect child tables.

Comment: do you have a reference for this ? the answer would be more complete with a reference supporting the assertion

Comment: Reference from postgres docs "A serious limitation of the inheritance feature is that indexes (including unique constraints) and foreign key constraints only apply to single tables, not to their inheritance children. This is true on both the referencing and referenced sides of a foreign key constraint. Thus, in the terms of the above example:" https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html

Answer (score 3):

When you first create the child table to can specify to automatically inherit the parent's indexes. (I have not found a way to active this after the child tables is already created).

> "The **LIKE ... INCLUDING ALL** indicates that we will copy in defaults,
>   primary keys, and index definitions. This now provides a
>   forward-looking way of managing all notes tables going forward.
>   Uniqueness criteria remains enforced on a per-table basis." https://dzone.com/articles/table-inheritance-whats-it-good-for

```sql
CREATE TABLE notes (
    id serial primary key,
    created_at timestamp not null default now(),
    created_by text not null,
    subject text not null,
    body text not null,
);


CREATE INDEX idx_notes_subject ON notes (subject);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE invoice_notes (
    child_field text not null,
    LIKE notes INCLUDING INDEXES, -- automatically inherit parent indexes
) INHERITS (notes);
```